# Angular autocomplete with filter:search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I'm looking for a "event" between "filter:search" and my Server-request using $http.

Like "autocomplete" on every input keystroke my $http should start a new request

```
<input ng-model="search">
<li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:search">
  {{friend.name}}
</li>
```

Pseudocode..

```
// set inputdata
var sPostData = "filter:search";

$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

$http.post(sUrl,sPostData).then(function(friendsResponse) {
 $scope.friends = friendsResponse.data.ResultSet.result;


});
```

Is there any hint or example to do this or wrong concept?

Comment: Have you considered bootstrap typeahead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do make autosuggestion-like functionality with AJAX data loading, then Angular filter is not right tool for this. Instead you can make use of `$scope.$watch` expression:

```
$scope.$watch('search', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        $http.post(sUrl, {filter: $scope.search}).then(function(friendsResponse) {
            $scope.friends = friendsResponse.data.ResultSet.result;
        });
    }
});
```

And corresponding HTML:

```
<input ng-model="search" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0} }">

<li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
    {{friend.name}}
</li>
```

Note, that you no longer need `| filter:search` part. I also added ngModelOptions for better experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-change` directive ie

HTML:

```
<input ng-model="search" ng-change="getData()">
<li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:search">
      {{friend.name}}
</li>
```

JS:

```
//call server on 'search' change

$scope.getData = function(){

    $http.post(.....)

}
```